# How to add validation in my form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

Рow should i add Required Field Validator and Range validator
My code is given below:

```
public ActionResult ContactUsForm()
{
    string userName = Request.Form["userName"];
    string email = Request.Form["mailId"];
    string phone = Request.Form["phoneNo"];
    string message = Request.Form["message"];

    SendMail(userName, email, phone, message);

    return View();
}
```

Comment: You're using MVC framework, there are no Web Forms controls here. The normal approach here is to create a View Model and use validation attributes on its properties.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing is very crude and simple way to do , but I understand as you may just have one form.

just add `required` word in the html tags for simple validation.

```
<input type="text" name="userName" required>
```